# Symfony - An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template

Tags: php, twig, symfony

I have been using Codeigniter for sometime now and thought I would try out Symfony. I am very new to Symfony and working from the demo project. When I launch the demo project in my browser I get this error:

```
An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("An exception occured in driver: could not find driver") in blog/index.html.twig at line 6.
500 Internal Server Error - Twig_Error_Runtime
3 linked Exceptions: DriverException » PDOException » PDOException »
```

I am not sure where to begin. Can someone please help me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2):

This is your problem: `An exception occured in driver: could not find driver`

It means that you haven't installed a proper driver for PDO for the RDBMS, which you are using. Or there is specified some invalid value in the config file.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu 16.04 doesn't come with php7 and sqlite3. Please run the following command

```
sudo apt-get install php7.0-sqlite3
```

Answer (score 0):

Once I ran `sudo apt-get install php5-sqlite` and then `composer install` everything started working.

Comment: I am having the same issue, but it is not working even after following above instructions.